# Typing a column of numbers (1,2,3...)

Tags: text-editing

I am writing a C# program containing these lines:

```
Console.Writeline("1");  
Console.Writeline("2");  
[...]  
Console.Writeline("26");
```

Is there a quick way to type the 26 numbers? I'm using Visual Studio and Notepad++ for editors, but suggestions which use others editors are also welcome.

Comment: You have written Console.Writeline("1)"; or Console.Writeline("1"); ?

Comment: Have you considered writing a `for` loop?

Comment: Some text editors can do this for you. In Notepad++, I can't check right now (using Linux), but I'd be surprised if you can't. You can certainly record and playback macros - if you can't insert the numbers where you want them, you can insert them somewhere else then use a macro to cut/paste them into place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, it depends what softwares you have.

with Excel/Calc, you can do that:

1. In A1 put: Console.Writeline("
2. In B1 put: 1
3. In C1 put: ");
4. In D1 put: =concatenate(A1;B1;C1)
5. Select from A1 to D1 and copy and paste to te first 26 rows
6. Select from D1 to D26, copy and paste cells to your code

with windows batch:

1. open cmd (start>execute>cmd)
2. write that in cmd and press enter: for /l %i in (1,1,26) do echo.Console.Writeline("%i");>>code.txt
3. write that in cmd and then copy to your code: notepad code.txt
4. write that in cmd to delete created .txt: del code.txt

Answer (score 3):

vim;

```
vim myfile
# Navigate to where you want the code. (Use hjkl to move)
i  # Enter insert mode
Console.Writeline("1")
esc # Enter command mode
qa # "start recording in register a"
# Duplicate the first line
yy
p
```

You should now see something like;

```
Console.Writeline("1")
Console.Writeline("1")
~
~
~
~
~
recording
```

Now place cursor at the 1 in the second line

```
Control a #increments the number
q #stop recording
```

Repeat the macro for as many lines as you want (in your case, 24 more times)

```
24@a
```

Comment: the vim way, hahahahah :)

Answer (score 2):

This C# code snippet will print out source code for you to copy and paste into your program:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 27; i++) {
    Console.Writeline("Console.Writeline(\"" + i.ToString() + "\");");
}
```

I really hope this is just a badly reduced sample of what you actually want to do.

Comment: I admit that the example is a bit goofy; I was just trying to illustrate the general problem.

Comment: well, you can create a simple sequencegenerator.exe, giving what you want as parameters, like: sequencegenerator.exe p1=Console.Writeline(\" p2=[1-27] p3="); tp1=text tp2=counter tp3=text (think that you can use it in future)